# const char ** and char **

Tags: c, constants

Code 1:  no warning , no error . work perfect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printP(const char *p)
{
    printf("const char *p is :  %p\n",p);
    if( p )
        printf("%s\n",p);
}

void printP2P(const char **p)
{
    printf("const char **p pointer to :     %p\n",*p);
    if( p &&(*p) )
        printf("%s\n",*p);
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "Hello World";
    const char *p = a;
    const char **p2p = &p;
    printP(p);
    printP2P(p2p);
    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:   can work.

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

```
const char *p = a;
==>
char *p = a;
```

Code 3 : Segementation fault.

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

```
const char **p2p = &p;
==>
const char **p2p = &a;
```

Problem:

1. Why code 2 could work but code 3 got a segement fault ?

2.When a pass `chat *` to `const char *` , no warning or error happened ,but when I assignment   `char **` to `const char **`, I got a warning, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume

```
a[] = 0x100 - H e l l o  w o r l d = 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c ...
p = 0x200 
p2p = 0x500
```

For 3rd case

```
p2p = &a
p2p = 0x100
```

and when you try to print it using `*p2p` you are trying `*0x100` which is reading memory at address stored at `0x100` which is `0x4865` (assuming 2 bytes address and doing away to endianness). The address `0x4865` most likely is not valid and reading it causes segmentation fault.

For 2nd case, its straight forward ...

```
p2p = &p
p2p = 0x200
*p2p = *0x200 = 0x100
```

---

Confusing part is that for array address `&a` is same as `a` which is same as `&a[0]`.

Comment: +1. Not so confusing after awhile. The C-standard covers it well in 6.2.5.20, and the second half of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005070/in-c-the-name-of-an-array-is-an-pointer-to-its-first-element-isnt-it/13005613#13005613) beats it somewhat to death.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yeah but I think OP is confused with that hence got that question.

Comment: I completely concur, thus "after awhile" and not right of the gate.