# assignment between const char** and char**

Tags: c

I am confused about the assignment between the two. Look at the follow code.

```
char **argv;
const char**p = argv;   // compile error

char * cp;
const char * ccp = cp;  // no compile error
```

But the question [one of the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671960/const-char-and-char) may have some conflicts with mine. He can compile with the above code. problem:
 how do I understand the assignment?

Comment: Why did you tag the question C?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why is it explicitly C++? Because of the unnecessary `#include <iostream>` line?

Comment: @Csq Well, that does make this C++ and not C. But maybe I over-reacted.

Comment: See here too: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/constptrptr-conversion.html

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. It should be C code originally. And thank you for your link. It helps.